# Difference between pointer to an array and array name as a pointer when used with increment operators

Tags: c, pointers, associations, operator-precedence

code 1:

```
int main()
{
    char ptr[]="uma";
    char *p;
    p=ptr;
    ++*p++;
    printf("%s",p);
    return 0;
}
```

code 2:

```
int main()
{
    char *ptr="uma";
    ++*ptr++;
    printf("%s",ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

#### code 1 is working fine and giving output as **"ma"**
  where as code2 is showing run time error .
what exactly is the difference between both of them

Comment: `++*p++;` don;t write code like that, parenthesis generally comes for free, you know?

Comment: An array is **not** a pointer!

Comment: @umamahesh  In the second program there is an attempt to change a string literal that results in undefined behavior. String literals may not be changed.

Comment: @SouravGhosh i tried to know precedence and association of increment operators that's why i wrote like that.

Comment: @umamahesh precision? Hows that? Did you mean precedence?

Comment: i mean array name it self points to first element in array ryt? so we can use it as a pointer . that's why i did. @Olaf

Comment: yeah @SouravGhosh